# Excel Data Queries - Ignore missing table / assign specific table number for every query

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a bit of trouble to create an automated report based on an HTML file. The file contains tables with data structured from the web page, and I just create tables from the tables recognized by Excel. So far it does what I need, but sometimes one or more tables from the HTML file is missing, and causing the tables to shuffle between them, like table 0 is missing then table 1 will take it's place and break the entire sheet because the wrong table is in the place of table 0.

What I wanted to know if it's a way to assign every query to a specific table number for each query. Like Table 0 will get the value from the specified query, not the first one that comes in the list of queries. The code so far is this for Power Query Editor:

```
let
Source = Web.Page(File.Contents("D:\AUTO.html")),
Data0 = Source{0}[Data]
in Data0
```

I use this code because the columns or rows will not always be the same, sometimes one can be missing and if I use the original code that is generated when getting the data from the page it will give errors and not load the table if there is a missing column/row.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**MissingField.Ignore**

When you use functions like *Table.SelectColumns* or *RenameColumns* or *ReorderColumns* you can use the **MissingField.Ignore** options to avoid the missing field error to stop your query

eg:

```
= Table.SelectColumns(#"blah",{"column1", "column2", "column3"}, MissingField.Ignore)
```

documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/missingfield-error